# Unable to either attach or create a .csv file (using CHCSVParser)

Tags: iphone, email, csv, attachment

I am having a problem either attaching or creating a .csv file in my app, I cannot figure out where the problem exists.  In the email view the .csv attachment is shown but when the email is received it has no attachment.  I send an array of objects (dataController.masterList) to the CHCSVWriter.  I've spent a lot of time this week trying solutions from other questions regarding email attachments and CHCSVWriter and obviously none of the solutions have worked so know I'm asking you. Where does the problem exist, and what do you suggest? 
Thank you in advance,
Happy Days, -Rob

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if (formatter == nil) {
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}

NSString *filepath = @"testfile.csv";
filepath = [filepath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

NSOutputStream *exportStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filepath append:NO];
NSStringEncoding encodingA = NSUTF8StringEncoding;

CHCSVWriter *csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithOutputStream:exportStream encoding:encodingA delimiter:','];
[csvWriter writeField:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"One"]];
[csvWriter writeLineOfFields:dataController.masterList];
[csvWriter closeStream];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filepath ofType:@".csv"];
NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mail setSubject:@"CSV File"];
    [mail addAttachmentData:mydata mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:filepath];
    [mail setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I stopped using the CHCSV writer and just wrote an array then combined the components of the array with a ",".

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if (formatter == nil) {
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}

NSIndexPath *index2 = 0;
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSString *holder;
NSArray *holderArray;
NSArray *saverArray;

while (i < dataController.countOfList) {

TimeSheetEntry *sAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:index2.row];

    NSString *dayhold = [formatter stringFromDate:sAtIndex.date];
    holderArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sAtIndex.name, sAtIndex.jobnum, sAtIndex.hours, sAtIndex.jobnotes, dayhold, nil];
    saverArray = [saverArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:holderArray];
    i++;
    NSIndexPath *index3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1];
    index2 = index3;
}

holder = [saverArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];//this is the seperating variable

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputFile = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timesheet.csv"];
NSError *csvError = NULL;

BOOL written = [holder writeToFile:outputFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&csvError];

if (!written)
    NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", csvError);


if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mail setSubject:@"CSV File"];
    //[mail setMessageBody:holder isHTML:YES];
    [mail addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:outputFile] mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"timesheet.csv"];
    [mail setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still wants to use CHCSVParser, I found that the file path has to be absolute:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:_tempManagedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_tempManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSURL *datapath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.csv"];

NSOutputStream *output = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToMemory];
CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithOutputStream:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding delimiter:','];

// Fetch objects to write to .csv
for (Task *task in fetchedObjects) {
    [writer writeLineOfFields:@[task.taskID, task.taskTitle, task.taskDescription]];
}

entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Journal"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:_tempManagedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
fetchedObjects = [_tempManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (JournalEntry *entry in fetchedObjects) {
    [writer writeLineOfFields:@[entry.day, entry.entryTitle, entry.entryDescription]];
}

[writer closeStream];

NSData *buffer = [output propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
[buffer writeToURL:datapath atomically:NO];
```